# C Segmentation Fault 11

Tags: c, gdb

I am writing small program regards question on USACO.

Question is posted as http://usacotraining.blogspot.co.uk/2013/09/problem-112-greedy-gift-givers.html

Here is my code for it:

```
    /*
ID: xin.sun2
LANG: C
TASK: gift1
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int searchIndex(char *list[], char* s, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i ++) {
        if (strcmp(list[i], s) == 0) {
            return i;
        }   
    }
    return -1;
}

int main() {

    freopen("gift1.in", "r", stdin);
    freopen("gift1.out", "w", stdout);

    int num_people = 0;
    scanf("%d", &num_people);

    char *nameList[num_people] = malloc(num_people*100*sizeof(char));
    int money[num_people];
    memset(money, 0, num_people*sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < num_people; i++) 
        scanf("%s", nameList[i]);

    char* this_people = malloc(100*sizeof(char));
    while (scanf("%s", this_people) != EOF) {
        int amount, num_giving, people_index;
        people_index = searchIndex(nameList, this_people, num_people);
        scanf("%d", &amount);
        scanf("%d", &num_giving);
        money[people_index] -= amount/num_giving*num_giving;
        int giving_amount = amount/num_giving;
        for (int i = 0; i < num_giving; i++) {
            char* p = malloc(100*sizeof(char));
            scanf("%s",p);
            int this_index = searchIndex(nameList, p, num_people);
            money[this_index] += giving_amount;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num_people; i++) {
        printf("%s %d\n", nameList[i], money[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It has no problem when I compile the .c file, but when I execute file. It shows segmentation fault 11. I did try to use gdb and the result is

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fff96b17908 in ?? ()
```

I have two questions:
1. What's wrong with my code (algorithms)? It might be syntax problem since I am really new to c programming
2. Why gdb shows ??() instead of the line number in main of where the problem is. Did I use gdb in the wrong way?

Thanks all!

**UPDATE**

I have correct the problem in regards to not sign space to array and char.
but there is a compile error

```
null.c:27:8: error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
        char *nameList[num_people] = malloc(num_people*100*sizeof(char));
```

I have question about the correct way to initialise array of string and how to pass array of string as parameter to a function.

Comment: in this loop `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) scanf("%s", nameList[i]);` replace `i<5` by `i<num_people`. lots of other incorrect statements though

Comment: You could initialize `nameList` in a loop, such as `for (int i = 0; i < num_people; i++) nameList[i] = malloc(100);`

Comment: Allocating memory 3 times with malloc and never freeing it is one of the problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char* this_people;
while (scanf("%s", this_people) != EOF) {
```

and

```
char* p;
scanf("%s",p);
```

is wrong, this_people and p point to nowhere, and scanf uses this "nowhere" as input buffer. Either use malloc() to allocate some memory, or make p an array. (You'll still have problems if the user enters something that's longer than the space you provide, but as you're learning, that won't be a problem until later).

When you have a problem like this, the gdb command `bt` is your friend. It shows you which functions were called from where after a crash.

For the namelist array, you want to use:

define:

```
char **namelist;
namelist=malloc(num_people*sizeof (char *));
```

or, but this needs "new" compilers, as it isn't in old C specifications:

```
char *namelist[num_people];
```

then, in each of the 2 cases:

```
for (i=0; i<num_people; i++)
    namelist[i]=malloc(100);
```

(You should check if malloc returns NULL and throw an error, but i omitted that for brevity).

Comment: Oh, and i just noticed `name_list` has the same problem, you don't allocate memory "behind" the pointers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have updated my code and some compiler error shows, not sure what is means by variable-size object may not be initialised.

Comment: I appended example code how to do the namelist correctly to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
char* this_people;
while (scanf("%s", this_people) != EOF) {
```

this_people requires storage space. To be of the form

```
char this_people[100]; //or some desired maximum storage
while (scanf("%s", this_people) != EOF) {
```

Also,

```
char *nameList[num_people];
```

allocates a bunch of pointers of type `char *`. Not any storage.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have updated my code and some compiler error shows, not sure what is means by variable-size object may not be initialised.

Answer (score 1):

1. The segmentation fault occurs because you try to write to memory does not allocated by yourself, as pointed out by other answers. To fix these problems, you have several options, you can define them as a fixed-length array, dynamically allocate memories for them by calling `malloc()`, or use `scanf("%ms", &p)` and let the glibc do the memory allocation for you.
2. GDB shows `?? ()` instead of line number and function name because it does not have enough information to show them. To fix this, you need to compile your program with `-g` (I suppose you are using `gcc`) and install debug information packages for the system libraries (glibc in this case) that your program needed. If you are using Fedora or CentOS, you can install the debug information package for glibc by `debuginfo-install glibc`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is there :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
    scanf("%s", nameList[i]);
```

the pointer `nameList[i]` has not been associated to any allocated memory location. You need to do something like :

```
char *nameList[num_people];
for (int i=0; i<num_people; i++)
    nameList[i] = malloc(30*sizeof(char)); // or any size you choose
```

Same stands for :

```
char* this_people;
```

Also, to have precise details in `gdb`, you need to compile your program with the `-g` flag (if using GCC).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have updated my code and some compiler error shows, not sure what is means by variable-size object may not be initialised.